# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, refinerycms

I've just started using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I can deploy a new rails 4.2.5 rails app no problem. I have a problem when deploying a brand new RefineryCMS.

Here are the commands I ran in order;

```
refinerycms refinerycms_aws_test
cd refinerycms_aws_test
```

add 'sqlite3' to the Gemfile

```
git init
g ca -m 'initial commit'
eb init
```

Answers to the questions;

- Server: Select 7 (Sydney)
- Application: Create new, "refinerycms"
- Ruby? yes
- Platform: 2 - (Ruby 2.1 Puma)

Now create the environment

```
eb create refinerycms-env
```

Set the secret token

```
eb setenv SECRET_KEY_BASE=27b39f037d544efc4671c707f68e54abcc6a61fa24a2664f0e4ae2871a932beb884288981eefcd4259a8c325ee44335231db04d6f58c8a75d3ac8d84e6e0dcf5
eb setenv SECRET_TOKEN=27b39f037d544efc4671c707f68e54abcc6a61fa24a2664f0e4ae2871a932beb884288981eefcd4259a8c325ee44335231db04d6f58c8a75d3ac8d84f6e0dce5
```

The error I get is 'page not found 404' here is what the `eb logs` command gives;

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/puma/puma.log
-------------------------------------
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:492:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:363:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-02-02 03:21:37 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:492:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:363:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-02-02 03:21:55 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:492:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:363:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-02-02 03:21:55 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:492:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:363:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:101:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-02-02 03:21:55 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
```

It's complaining about the secret_token and secret_key_base but I've set both of these. They show up when I use `eb printenv`

**UPDATE**

Here is my secrets.yml file

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %>
```

I've set both of these through the eb tool.

**UPDATE**

I added ssh to my elastic beanstalk environment and logged in. I did a `env` command and found that my SECRET environment variables are listed there. So they are getting set.

Comment: Check your settings at config/secrets.yml, does `secret_key_base` and `secret_token` get the value from env?

Comment: Yes I have both listed in my secrets.yml file and I've added them through eb setenv on the server. I'm thinking that refineryCMS may have another secrets.yml file?